# Get reified type of symbol after the erasure phase of the Scala 2.9.3 compiler

Tags: c++, scala, compiler-construction, erasure

I'm writing a compiler plugin that translates a subset of Scala to C++ (ignore the apparent insanity of this task). I'm using a number of plugins that must run after the erasure phase. However, I require the full type information to output valid code.

For example, for the Scala;

```
def foo(f: Type1 => Type2): Unit = { /* Snip */ }
```

I'd like to output the C++;

```
void foo(scala::Function1<Type1, Type2> f) { /* Snip */ }
```

However, after the erasure phase, `foo` looks like this:

```
def foo(f: Function1): Unit = { /* Snip */ }
```

I.e., the generic type information for the parameter, `f`, has been lost. I need to get it back some how. Any suggestions?

**Reply to cdshines' comment**

Here is an example:

`example.scala`

```
object Example {
  def func(f: Int => Boolean) { }
}
```

When I compile;

```
# scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.9.3 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
# scalac -Xprint:explicitouter -Xprint:erasure example.scala
[[syntax trees at end of explicitouter]]// Scala source: example.scala
package <empty> {
  final object Example extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object Example = {
      Example.super.this();
      ()
    };
    def func(f: Int => Boolean): Unit = ()
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of erasure]]// Scala source: example.scala
package <empty> {
  final object Example extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object Example = {
      Example.super.this();
      ()
    };
    def func(f: Function1): Unit = ()
  }
}
```

Note the change in the signature of `func`. `explicitouter` is the phase before `erasure`.

Comment: Are you sure about that erasure? What stage do you get that on? I can't reproduce that with scala 2.9.3.

Comment: @cdshines I've replied in the question.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could pass additional type info in `ClassTags`?

Comment: Sadly, ClassTag don't exist in 2.9.3. I'm not sure if they'd help at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was suggested by the scala-language mailing list. Inside something that imports `scala.tools.nsc.Global`'s namespace, the following will recover the type of a method (more specifically a `DefDef` in the AST) before the `erasure` phase.

```
atPhase(currentRun.erasurePhase) { someDefDef.symbol.tpe }
```